# SQLite - Merge 2 tables according to modified date, insert a new row if necessary

Tags: sqlite

I have a table having an ID column, this column is a primary key and unique as well. In addition, the table has a modified date column.

I have the same table in 2 databases and I am looking to merge both into one database. The merging scenario in a table is as follows:

- Insert the record if the ID is not present;
- If the ID exists, only update if the modified date is greater than that of the existing row.

For example, having:

**Table 1:**

```
id | name | createdAt  | modifiedAt
---|------|------------|-----------
1  | john | 2019-01-01 | 2019-05-01
2  | jane | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-03
```

**Table 2:**

```
id | name | createdAt  | modifiedAt
---|------|------------|-----------
1  | john | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-30
2  | JANE | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-04
3  | doe  | 2019-01-01 | 2019-05-01
```

The resulting table would be:

```
id | name | createdAt  | modifiedAt
---|------|------------|-----------
1  | john | 2019-01-01 | 2019-05-01
2  | JANE | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-04
3  | doe  | 2019-01-01 | 2019-05-01
```

I've read about `INSERT OR REPLACE`, but I couldn't figure out how the date condition can be applied. I know as well that I can loop through each pair of similar row and check the date manually but this would be very time and performance consuming. Therefore, is there an efficient way to accomplish this in SQLite?

I'm using `sqlite3` on Node.js .

Comment: Do you want to create a new table by merging these 2 tables, or do the merging inside say Table1?

Comment: No problem with either. Both works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) notation added in Sqlite 3.24 makes this easy:

```
INSERT INTO table1(id, name, createdAt, modifiedAt)
  SELECT id, name, createdAt, modifiedAt FROM table2 WHERE true
  ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE
  SET (name, createdAt, modifiedAt) = (excluded.name, excluded.createdAt, excluded.modifiedAt)
  WHERE excluded.modifiedAt > modifiedAt;
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the table `Table3`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 (
    id  INTEGER,
    name    TEXT,
    createdat   TEXT,
    modifiedat  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

and then insert the rows like this:

```
insert into table3 (id, name, createdat, modifiedat)
select id, name, createdat, modifiedat from (
  select * from table1 t1
  where not exists (
    select 1 from table2 t2
    where t2.id = t1.id and t2.modifiedat >= t1.modifiedat
  )  
  union all 
  select * from table2 t2 
    where not exists (
    select 1 from table1 t1
    where t1.id = t2.id and t1.modifiedat > t2.modifiedat
  )  
)
```

This uses a `UNION ALL` for the 2 tables and gets only the needed rows with `EXISTS` which is a very efficient way to check the condition you want. 
I have `>=` instead of `>` in the `WHERE` clause for `Table1` in case the 2 tables have a row with the same `id` and the same `modifiedat` values.
In this case the row from `Table2` will be inserted.
If you want to merge the 2 tables in `Table1` you can use [`REPLACE`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/):

```
replace into table1 (id, name, createdat, modifiedat)
select id, name, createdat, modifiedat 
from table2 t2
where 
  not exists (
    select 1 from table1 t1
    where (t1.id = t2.id and t1.modifiedat > t2.modifiedat)
  )
```